# How do I load a module catalog from a database in Prism?

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm using Prism in my WPF application and up to now, I've been loading the modules via `var moduleCatalog = new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();`. I'd like to get the module catalog from a database. The Prism documentation indicates that this is possible, but it doesn't go into any details.

Has anyone done this and can provide some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a theoretical possibility, but it's not in any samples I've seen.

Basically what you'd do is either base64 encode the DLLs / Files into the database or zip them up and store them in one blob.  You'd download them in your bootstrapper and copy them locally (in a temp directory) and then allows them to load normally from the filesystem using the DirectoryModuleCatalog.  If you wanted it to be a bit more elegant, you could write your own ModuleCatalog that encapsulates this logic.

This is very similar to what I do... I actually download a zip file of all of the modules from a website at launch time and unzip them and load them with the DirectoryModuleCatalog.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own `ModuleCatalog` implementation by implementing `IModuleCatalog`.  Your implementation can then populate the catalog by any means you define.

You could also use the [`CreateFromXAML` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654264.aspx) that accepts a `Stream` and implement a webservice that delivers the ModuleCatalog in XAML over HTTP.